# Using OpenCV DNN Detection for images over 300x300

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, caffe, detection, face-detection

I am here because I am in need of some advise...

I am working with face detection. I already tried some methods like de DLIB Detector, HoG, among others...

For now, I started to use the OpenCV DNN Detection based in the ResNet .caffemodel, but after a lot of attempts I realize that this model it is not very good for images over than 300x300 (HxW).

Note that my images are 1520x2592 (HxW). When I apply the resize, almost all information of the faces are lost because the faces in the original image are about 150x150 pixels, when resized for detection using DNN their size is about 30x20 (approx.).

Some approaches I already tried:
- Split figure in sub-figures
- Background subtraction

What I need to reach:
- Fast detection
- Reduce the number of lost faces (not detected)

Challenge:
- Big image with small faces in it
- A lot of area in the image not being used (but I can't change the location of the camera)

Comment: train an appropriate network or use multiple subimages. If your network is fully convolutional, you can just feed bigger images to it (which will make the inference slower)

Answer (score 0):

SSD-based networks are fully convolutional that means you can vary input size. Try to pass inputs of different sizes and choose one which give satisfying performance and accuracy. There is an example here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/202995/dnn-module-face-detection-poor-results-open-cv-343/

```
input = blobFromImage(img, 1.0, Size(1296, 760));  // x0.5
```

or

```
input = blobFromImage(img, 1.0, Size(648, 380));  // x0.25
```